# mysql won't autostart

Tags: mysql, boot

I'm running ubuntu 10.04, since I upgraded to mysql 5.5 it stopped starting at bootime.
I tried `sysv-rc-conf mysql on` because it was actually set to "off" but still won't boot.
I have to manually run `service mysql start` everytime which will make it start in 2 seconds, also the log shows no errors!

Comment: Are there any log messages indicating that the system tried to start it during bootup but failed?

Comment: nothing, I just tried to reboot and there's no trace of mysql

Answer (score 1):

Go and edit

```
/etc/init/mysql.conf
```

and be sure that you have the lines (somewhere near the top, check if they're not commented):

```
start on (net-device-up
      and local-filesystems)
```

Meaning that it will start when networking is up and local filesystems are mounted.

Comment: it was already like that